# Using S3 instead of MinIO for video management

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, amazon-api-gateway, minio

I am relatively new to AWS so I wanted to reach out to the gurus in the community to get some advice on architecture, and I thought I would share my thoughts.

I am building out cloud infrastructure for a Video Management Software for a Body Worn Camera system. We are talking lots of video footage being uploaded to the cloud.

So my initial thoughts are:

1. EC2 8 vCPUs, 32 GB RAM, 512 GB storage, Debian (allocated Elastic IP)
2. RDS for PostgreSQL
3. S3 for storage

Now connecting the EC2 to the S3 seems to be done via IAM role, so I have done that and created an IAM role called "full_s3_access_from_ec2", now the S3 is available to the EC2 through AWS CLI e.g.

```
aws s3 ls s3://tactical-zepcam-s3-storage
```

The issue I have is that the application storage system was designed and provisioned for **MinIO** and expects an **https end point** and **username** and **password**, so I am not sure that using AWS CLI is an option.

I thought to overcome my issues with application access and authentication from EC2 to S3 I could use the AWS API Gateway, I just wanted to check with the community if I am overthinking this and if there is a better way?

If I did go down the route of configuring an API, which one should I use "Web Socket API" or "HTTP API"?

Answer (score 0):

We have successfully setup an EC2 connect to an s3 bucket in AWS. You need to create an access key to interact with the s3 API:

The url has the form https://s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com
Where eu-west-3 is your region.
And you need an user with the AmazonS3FullAccess permissions

You do not need the AWS API Gateway Console

Comment: Generally EC2 instances use an instance role to provide permissions such as S3 permissions, rather than setting up an access key. It might be that this specialized use case requires use of an access key. Perhaps you could add a bit more detail to your answer to help others who try this in future, it's fairly high level right now.

Comment: Thanks Tim, the main issue I had was I needed to access S3 from the EC2 over HTTPS and I figured out how to do that with the access key, so basically solved my own issue. My confusion originally was that I only seemed to be able to access the S3 from the EC2 via the AWS CLI tooling. Thanks for you comment though it is much appreciated.